# Does 1 Thess 2:16 imply a dating of the letter near the destruction of 70AD?

Tags: chronology, pauline-epistles, 1-thessalonians, jerusalem

The context of the passage, ~vss.14-16, concerns the suffering of the churches, including the Thessalonians, and particularly the Jewish persecutors/persecution of Christ's people.

The [end of vs.16, translation-dependent](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Thess+2%3A14-16&version=HCSB;SBLGNT), reads:

> . . . and wrath has overtaken them at last [HCSB].
> . . . ἔφθασεν δὲ ἐπ’ αὐτοὺς ἡ ὀργὴ εἰς τέλος. [SBL GNT]

This feel of 'termination' language is unusual in Pauline texts, despite his many complaints about the conduct of his fellow Jews.

Doesn't this imply some sort of 'event' that gained Paul's attention enough for such language to leak through to this letter?

Answer (score 3):

An interesting question

“but wrath has come upon them to the uttermost.” [NKJV] is the most difficult statement in this passage to understand and is open to several interpretations.

In Paul's writings God’s wrath is predominantly an eschatological event. Evil done by Jews or Gentiles earns God’s wrath, which will be executed on the day of wrath, (Rom 2:5). Often he presents that fate is only avoidable by faith in the Lord Jesus Christ (Rom 5:9, 1 Thess 1:10; 5:9)

However Paul also speaks of the wrath of God being manifested before that final day, even through pagan agency (Rom 1:18; 13:4–5). So, Paul's use of the wrath of God does not provide conclusive evidence.

So what was the wrath “that has come upon” the Jews?

The aorist verb "ἔφθασεν" would appear to refer to an actual event Paul was interpreting as a manifestation of divine wrath. However he could have been referring to several events:

1) He could have had reference to the fall of Jerusalem,67 the expulsion of Jews from Rome by Claudius (Acts 18:2),

2) the famine of A.D. 46 (Acts 11:28),

3) or other events.

The Greek behind “at last” or "uttermost" (εἰς τέλος) is also problematic. If the sentence is translated assuming a terrible event had befallen the Jews, then “at last” is appropriate. This temporal use of εἰς τέλος is also implied by the parallel structures of v. 16b and v. 16c; that is, a temporal “always” calls for a temporal “at last.”

The alternative translation “uttermost” or “forever”/ "fully" is lexically possible and would indicate the translators assumption that the wrath Paul is speaking about here is an eschatological event not a temporal one. The resultant meaning being that wrath had accrued to the Jews in anticipation of the end, when God’s judgement will fall on all who persist in disobedience. Such a reading allows for a temporal meaning of τέλος and avoids presuming that Paul was referring to some unnamed tragedy.

So the answer I would give is '**Yes it is possible, but we are not given enough information by Paul to be definite**'

I would just add that if Paul was referring to some tragedy that had befallen the Jewish opponents of the gospel, it would appear that he would have considered that disaster as a foretaste of the judgement awaiting them at the ultimate day of wrath.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion and say that the "wrath" is already upon those that reject the Gospel-period. This was prophesied by John the Baptist, Jesus, and Paul in numerous instances. To make it a condition of 'already fulfilled' when it is to be understood in a continuous active sense diminishes it's true meaning.

Answer (score 2):

**Paul Referred to the Death of Agrippa I**

Assuming that this part of Thessalonians is genuinely Pauline, I suggest that Paul was looking back to the death of Herod Agrippa I, the last "King of the Jews." This theory works better with "in the end" than "at last," for Agrippa had died several years earlier. But his death, which was quite famous, fits with the idea that God punished the Jews for persecuting Christians. It also solves our problem of "termination language," referring to the apparent end of the Herodian dynasty, rather than to the destruction of the Temple.

To begin, we need to distinguish between the two Agrippas. When Acts refers to "Agrippa," it means Agrippa II who eventually held the title of *praetor* but never "king." His earlier namesake is called simply "Herod."

[Agrippa I](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Agrippa_I) had been an effective ruler, so much so that the Romans eventually allowed him to govern a territory even greater than Herod the Great. He was popular among the Jews, because he supported the Temple financially and participated in its rites. To Christians, however, he was an enemy. *Acts* portrays him as persecuting Christians, including killing James and imprisoning Peter.  Acts 12 states:

> About that time Herod [Agrippa] the king laid violent hands upon some who
> belonged to the church. He killed James the brother of John with the
> sword; and when he saw that it pleased the Jews, he proceeded to
> arrest Peter also.. [after a miraculous release] Peter came to
> himself, and said, “Now I am sure that the Lord has sent his angel and
> rescued me from the hand of Herod and from all that the Jewish people
> were expecting.”

Agrippa's death is depicted in the same chapter, which seems to imply that it was a product of divine retribution, perhaps the same "wrath" about which Paul wrote decades before the composition of Acts:

> On an appointed day Herod put on his
> royal robes, took his seat upon the throne, and made an oration to
> them. And the people shouted, “The voice of a god, and not of man!”
> Immediately an angel of the Lord smote him, because he did not give
> God the glory; and he was eaten by worms and died.

After Agrippa's death, the Roman Emperor Claudius decided to return  the province of Iudaea to the rule of Roman procurators, as had been the case during the time of Jesus' when Pontius Pilate governed the area. Although his son and namesake would eventually succeed him in a lesser role, Agrippa I was thus the last "King of the Jews."

**Agrippa's death must have been a tremendous relief to Christians, so much so that it was retained in detail in Acts, decades later. It makes sense that, just as Acts'  Peter would express gratitude at being rescued from Agrippa and "the Jewish people," Paul would declare his approval that God's wrath had come upon this same persecutor of the church, together with those who supported him.**

Comment: An insightful observation, +1

Answer (score 0):

This does refer to a major catastrophe that befell the Jews, with the only known event that fits the bill being the destruction of the temple in Jerusalem. It was one of the reasons that contributed to F. C. Baur's rejection of 1 Thessalonians as a genuine Pauline letter. Although First Thessalonians is now accepted as almost certainly a genuine letter by the apostle Paul, therefore written long before the destruction, if it were proven that this is a reference to the events of 70 CE, then this could reopen the question of authorship.

There are several known interpolations in in Paul's epistles, as well as some suspected interpolations and alterations, so the first consideration should be whether this verse, or the passage containing the verse, is a late interpolation. Raymond E. Brown explains, in *An Introduction to the New Testament*, page 463, arguments against Pauline authorship of 1 Thessalonians 2 :13-16, but also those for his authorship.

If 1 Thessalonians 2:16 does indeed refer to the destruction of 70 CE, this need only mean that one verse, or perhaps a few verses, date from this period, not necessarily the epistle as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

The correct translation is:

> the wrath [of God] has come **upon them** **unto the end**
>
> *ephthasen de **ep' autous** e ourgi **eis telos***

"Uttermost" is a highly irregular and improper translation of the word for "end" here.  *Telos* is like the English word "end" in that it can mean both "end [point]" and "goal or purpose [for which something is made or done]." In fact, it is more or less exactly synonymous. So unless you have very good reason to suppose otherwise, "unto the end" should be translated... "unto the end." Indeed, the Latin also has, "in finum" (unto the end).

The meaning is that God has cursed the Jews (or rather they have cursed themselves explicitly — "may his blood be upon us, and upon our children" Matt 27:25) for the abominable act of deicide (the murder of God — Acts 5:30) and rejection of both His Covenant and Messiah, reminiscent of Cain killing Abel in jealousy and pride, and being cast out in perpetuity — being analogous to the Jewish people post-Christ, both in that they killed their brother Jesus, because their sacrifices were inferior to His final and pleasing Sacrifice, and that they were consequently scattered abroad as vagabonds and fugitives on the earth (see history since the Crucifixion), and that everyone has hated them for this throughout history: "all who see me shall seek to kill me."

It does not imply that the Temple has been destroyed or that it will nearly be destroyed, but is wider in scope, and has to do with the standing of the Jews before God, post Christ: namely, do they accept God's Covenant and Messiah, looking to the Cross for redemption (like the Apostles and first Christians), or do they stand condemned by God for deicide, being complicit as all non- and pre-Christians do. There is, for Paul, no 'dual Covenant' notion, of God putting up both with those who obey His Covenant and His Messiah, and those who wholesale reject both. If anything, there is a harsher punishment for those who reject the Christ from among His people, than from among the Gentiles, since, "whosoever will not obey that Prophet shall be cut off from among the people" (Acts 3:23).

Comment: It is possible to understand the referent here to be gentile authorities who caused the church, ('you, brethren, became imitators of the churches of God in Christ Jesus which are in Judea; for you suffered the same things from your own countrymen as they did from the Jews')?

Comment: The referent is "the Jews." The Gentile authorities were mere tools of the Jewish authorities, as evidenced by Acts, which states Pilate wanted to release Jesus but they instisted He be crucified and that His blood be upon them, from which Pilate washed his hands.